# Using matlab with Gitlab CICD: The job gets stuck indefinitely without running matlab

Tags: matlab, gitlab

I am using MATLAB 2023b and win-11, and using Gitlab (installed on a private cloud infra)
I want to set up a CICD pipeline and run the MATLAB code when I push the code to repo.

I used this script in my gitlab yaml file.

```
stages:
  - Test

Testing:
  tags:
    - matlab-win
  stage: Test
  script:
    - matlab -batch "runner"
```

where "runner.m" is my MATLAB file.
runner.m is as below
`a = 10; b = 12; disp(a+b)`

This takes an indefinite amount of time to run and nearing the pipeline timeout it sends this warning:

```
WARNING: Failed to terminate process: failed to attach to the console of the process being terminated: Access is denied.
WARNING: Failed to force-kill: exit status 128
```

I tried using admin access too but the issue is same.

I checked the task manager as well and can see MATLAB running as background process when the CI pipeline runs, but is using too less CPU and memory.

Any inputs?

Comment: [This forum post](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/341799-how-to-run-matlab-files-in-batch-mode-or-as-a-batch-process) mentions that you explicitly need to quit MATLAB at the end of your script in batch mode...

Comment: @vatbub while MATLAB hanging open for some reason (such as something internal to the OP's `runner` script hanging) might be the root cause, the forum post you've linked to is the "old way" of running MATLAB from the command line. The OP is using the newer `-batch` flag which (according to the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html)) should "exit automatically"

Comment: @sjain can you post your `runner.m` code as an [edit]? Can you swap it for a trivially simple script which just displays something to the command line with `disp` and then finishes so you can verify that it (a) is running and (b) is exiting correctly with a trivial script? That would enable you to rule out the code itself...

Comment: @Wolfie Its a just a simple script

`a = 10; b = 12; disp(a+b)`

Comment: @Wolfie 
another thing is that when I use my gitlab-runner as a linux machine, it works; but it doesnt work if runner is windows

Comment: If this works under Linux but not Windows, it could be an installation problem. Are you able to run MATLAB on that Windows instance manually? Can you run `matlab -batch "runner"` from a command line?

Comment: @CrisLuengo when i run matlab on the windows manually, either via gui or cmdline it works smooth without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I got the issue
gitlab-runner service wasnt running with admin access. I gave it the admin access and now its working fine.